# Inserting fields in the Invoice History Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, frontend, magento-1.9, invoice

I managed to enter the invoice_totals block, however my goal is to insert the block "Invoice History", follow the example:

[image]

The code for this:

```
    <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="teste" template="module/name/sales/order/view/nota_fiscal.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
```

I need add this same field, but in Invoice History, like this:

[image]

This to create a new invoice, Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

try with this code :

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_addcomment>
    <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_comments_view"  name="test" template="module/name/sales/order/view/nota_fiscal.phtml"></block>
</adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_addcomment>
```